# Can/Will SE make the calendar popup that shows days you have visited public?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, consecutive-days

When you click on the link for the number of consecutive days that you have visited an SE site you see this:

[image: Calender visits]

However, on a fellow user profile you only see this:

[image: User visits]

It only tells you the last time they have been to the site. It doesn't even tell you how many consecutive visits they have.

I realize this might be a privacy thing, but that is a pretty lame reason. You visited the site and likely posted, too. What's the big deal if someone can see your calendar? Wouldn't be too hard to make it a setting in the preferences so that you could turn it off if you wanted.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do such a thing? My calendar, I can see how that might be interesting if I'm trying to get a badge but someone else's?

Comment: @ben Why on Earth would I not?

Comment: Because you're looking at the days someone visited the site. It's not exactly interesting and probably won't influence anything... seems a bit pointless. It was a serious question, you're asking for a change to the functionality of the site and haven't provided a reason. Why would you want to?

Comment: @ben It is interesting to see how interested in the site people are. Maybe not on SO but on the other sites I think so. Also, I had a thought to run as a mod one day and it would be proof that I regularly visit.

Comment: There are much, much better indicators for interest in the site than the mere visiting times - comments, reviews, questions, answers.... all of which are visible publicly already.

Comment: `seen` is useful to find out if someone is likely to have read your comment, but visit history feels very intrusive to me.

Comment: @fredsbend - Hi. Please don't add anything in your question body which is not related to it. Also [voting is different here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: One "pro" of making consecutive days public (opt-in only of course) is that it shows commitment and makes for a nice anecdote when SO comes up in an interview if the number is really high.

Answer (score 9):

SE is not a social network.  This actually comes close to stalking in my book. I personally wouldn't like my visiting data to be public. And I don't see any need or use for this feature either.

> It is interesting to see how interested in the site people are. Maybe not on SO but on the other sites I think so.

Why is it interesting? And don't badges display this reasonably well? What possible use to the site will this have?

> Also, I had a thought to run as a mod one day and it would be proof that I regularly visit.

There are much better things to look for in a mod candidate, like proficiency with community moderation tools. And activity in the same. This is publicly available in the user activity page.

Comment: You: `I personally wouldn't like my visiting data to be public.` Me: `Wouldn't be too hard to make it a setting in the preferences so that you could turn it off if you wanted.`

Comment: @fredsbend but why would anybody want to make this public in the first place?

Comment: @fredsbend If it's opt-out, I'd still be against it, because these things shouldn't be forced onto someone. If it's opt-in, I don't see anyone using it. Also, what Pekka said.